# How to setup Hubot basic permissions?

Tags: hubot

How do I setup basic user permissions so users can't run commands like "Hubot die" or "Hubot show storage"?

I can see there is a script called hubot-auth but that seems to be for implementing it in other scripts and not controlling existing commands.

Comment: Can the person who downvoted please explain why they've downvoted and requested it be closed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a small chapter about it in [Automation and Monitoring with Hubot](https://leanpub.com/automation-and-monitoring-with-hubot) book (shameless plug). Excerpt:

### Assigning Roles

Only Admin users can assign roles. You don't have to create a role before assigning. All you have
to do is tell Hubot who is who using `hubot <user> has <role> role`. And you no longer have to use
those cryptic IDs anymore:

```
Tomas     hubot Jesse Pinkman has developer role
Hubot     Tomas: Ok, Jesse Pinkman has the 'developer' role.
```

Check the assigned roles using `hubot what roles does <user> have?`:

```
Tomas     hubot what roles does Jesse Pinkman have?  
Hubot     Tomas: Jesse Pinkman has the following roles: developer.
```

To remove the role from somebody, use `hubot <user> does not have <role> role`:

```
Tomas     hubot Jesse Pinkman does not have developer role
Hubot     Tomas: Ok, Jesse Pinkman doesn't have the 'developer' role.
```

You can assign multiple roles to multiple users.

### Applying Roles

Now, time to break the bad news. While Hubot Auth is pretty flexible, you will have to edit your
scripts to apply those roles. Luckily, there is not much to edit. There is a simple function that
checks if user has a role - `robot.Auth.hasRole(msg.envelope.user, '<role>')`.
This is how you use it in a script:

```
module.exports = (robot) ->
  robot.respond /do dangerous stuff/i, (msg) ->
    if robot.auth.hasRole(msg.envelope.user, 'developer')
      doDangerousStuff(msg)
    else
      msg.reply "Sorry, you don't have 'developer' role"

  doDangerousStuff = (msg) ->
    msg.send "Doing dangerous stuff"
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the original answer, you have to be a Hubot admin in order to assign roles. To define the Hubot admins, you have to set the `HUBOT_AUTH_ADMIN` environment variable to a comma-delimited string of IDs of the admins.  If you're using Slack, you can use their [API](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list/test) to figure the IDs of the users that should be admins.  For Slack these IDs will look something like `U123ABC1D`.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that `hubot die` is defined in the `ping.coffee` script. Maybe you can have a check there on authorized users when the command is run?

Something like this?

```
if msg.message.user.name in [authorized_user1, authorized_user2,..]
  # Do more stuff
```

The same can be done for the other show storage script too. I am not really sure if this is the best way to go about it though as you will have to modify all the scripts that you do not want to be executed.

A cleaner approach would be to set the list of users as a env variable at startup(kind of like what hubot-auth does) and then check it inside each script instead of hard coding user names.

Hope that helps.